# Open .scd files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program with python that downloads a large .scd file, unpacks it, and then installs it. It is not at all difficult for me to download it or install it, (which is pretty much just using urllib and moving a few files around) but unpacking it seems to be a problem. After a couple hours of Googling I can't seem to find any modules for Python capable of opening .scd archives. One idea is to try to convert is to a .zip file with Python, replace the .scd with that, and the just use zipfile.extractall(). I am fine with this if someone can tell me how to do the conversion. The conversion/extraction MUST be automated.

EDIT: It is OK with me if a use 3rd party software, but I still would like the following things: the process must be totally automated, (the user does not have to hit an extract button or anything along those lines) the 3rd party software must have a license that allows me to use it as part of my Python program, (and distribute it as part of my program's package to the general public) and the software is compatible with Windows.

Comment: You can't assume we all know what a .scd archive is. What type of archive is it?

Comment: @WilliamDenman I am not sure what you mean. I am not aware of various "types" of archives. Here is page with information about .scd files: http://file-extension.paretologic.com/detail.php/File-Extension-scd Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The `scd` file type is non-standard. The average programmer will have never encountered it. Your link is still confusing. It lists three different applications of the `scd` file type. Which one is it? In you r question you need to supply more information about what methods have you tried to convert from scd to zip.

Comment: tar, zip, gzip, rar etc. are all archive or compression file types.

Comment: @WilliamDenman I have not tried anything because I have not come across anything I think will work. The scd belongs to none of those applications, it is for a program a friend made that he would like to make available to the general public. He asked me to make him an installer.

Comment: @WilliamDenman I see. I thought by types you meant categories. Scd is a file type in its own right, and thus is non of those.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after numerous hours on google I found out that .scd's are basically .zip's with a 0% compression rate. Try using the built in zipfile module on your file as though it were a .zip.